# Is it possible to tar only sub directories excluding other files in the folder?

Tags: shell-script, tar

For example, suppose `A/B/C` is the main directory. Under the `C` directory,  I will have sub-directories and files. But I want to tar only the directories with its own name as below

If the directories under c are Test1 Test2 - I want them as Test1.tar Test2.tar

This is on a Linux machine.

Comment: And how do you want them to be added to the archive? Should they keep the same structure? Should all directories be brought to the same level? Please [edit] your question and show us i) a detailed example of the current directory structure (ideally, use the command `tree`) and ii) what you want to happen when you un-tar your tar file in a new location.

Comment: For example: do you want to tar the directories A and B? Do you want to tar the files in C? Or do want to tar only the content of Test1 and Test2?

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `tar` not to recurse into its arguments, and then use `find` to provide it with every directory as an argument. So, something like this:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 tar --no-recursion -cf your_tree.tar
```

The `-print0` and `-0` are to avoid problems with directories that have spaces and other special characters in their name.

As pointed out in comments below, if you have a lot of directories then the command line would become too big and `tar` would end up being invoked multiple times. In that case you could instead read the arguments using `--files-from`:

```
find . -type d -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion --files-from - -cf your_tree.tar
```

Edit:

The above was written before the OP clarified that they wanted a set of tar files in the top level directory. I think the above technique can still be used to achieve this. For example:

```
$ mkdir -vp tree/a/b/c tree/foo/bar/baz                                                                                 
mkdir: created directory ‘tree’
mkdir: created directory ‘tree/a’
mkdir: created directory ‘tree/a/b’
mkdir: created directory ‘tree/a/b/c’
mkdir: created directory ‘tree/foo’
mkdir: created directory ‘tree/foo/bar’
mkdir: created directory ‘tree/foo/bar/baz’
$ touch tree/foo/an_unwanted_file
$ cd tree
/var/tmp/tree
$ for dir in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d); do if [ "$dir" != "." ]; then find "$dir" -type d -print0 | tar --null --no-recursion --files-from - -cvf "${dir}.tar"; fi; done
./a/
./a/b/
./a/b/c/
./foo/
./foo/bar/
./foo/bar/baz/
$ tar tvf foo.tar                                                                                                       
drwxr-xr-x andy/andy         0 2018-11-29 12:30 ./foo/
drwxr-xr-x andy/andy         0 2018-11-29 12:30 ./foo/bar/
drwxr-xr-x andy/andy         0 2018-11-29 12:30 ./foo/bar/baz/
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── b
│       └── c
├── a.tar
├── foo
│   ├── an_unwanted_file
│   └── bar
│       └── baz
└── foo.tar
```

Comment: Note that `tar` may be invoked several times when run like this through `xargs`. Each new invocation would truncate the archive.

Comment: Hmm, I think that would only happen if you had many many thousands of directories wouldn't it? But yeah I can see how that might happen. I think you can work around that one by using `--files-from -` instead. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Also, if a directory `a/b/c` is added, it would be added again when the `a/b` directory was processed... I think (haven't tested).

Comment: Thanks Grifferz. But the names of folders should be dynamic as in question's example. This will not work for me.

Comment: You can still build on what I have shown above to do what you want. I will edit in an example which should set you on the right lines.

Comment: @Bhavya the question's example is very unclear. Once again: please edit your question and include an actual directory structure and then show what you would like to get from the tar file. Use `tree` as shown in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for dir in A/B/C/*/; do
    name=$(basename "$dir")
    tar -cv -f "$name.tar" -C A/B/C "$name"
done
```

This would create an archive for each individual (non-hidden) subdirectory under `A/B/C`. The archives would be created in the current directory.

The `-C` option makes `tar` set the working directory for the following files (`$name`).

You could use `-C "$(dirname "$dir")"` in place of `-C A/B/C` for slightly more generic code.

---

To create the archives under the `C` subdirectory

```
( cd A/B/C &&
  for dir in */; do
      tar -cv -f "${dir%/}.tar" "$dir"
  done )
```

The subshell around the whole command prevents the working directory from being changed in the rest of the shell/script, and `${dir%/}` removes the trailing slash at the end of the value in `$dir`.

Unfortunately, the `-C` option does not affect the working directory for the archive file specified by `-f`, otherwise we could just have moved the `-C` bit before the `-f` option.

Alternatively, as a variant of the first loop:

```
for dir in A/B/C/*/; do
    name=$( basename "$dir" )
    ( cd "$( dirname "$dir" )" && tar -cv -f "$name.tar" "$name" )
done
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use `star` (I am the author of `star`which is the oldest free tar implementation):

```
star cf file.tar -find . -type d
```

This works for any number of names in the tar file since `star` uses `libfind`-